# Ubuntu upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 failed - Dell

Tags: upgrade

When upgrading from ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04..system installs upgrades and hangs at one or the other place....have tried it three times....here are the issues i face

1. update installation fails at one or the other place
2. there after system does not start and i have to go back to factory settings (12.04)
3. cannot try this process repeatedly as first i have to upgrade 12.04 to latest then download 1900+ files for 14.04 and then installation starts which fails
4. entire cycle takes 3-4 hours...
5. have tried one suggested command to un-install cinnamon....did not work

plz suggest steps with complete instructions to upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04 (new to Linux)

or suggest a full proof process to move to 14.04 - format and direct installation tof 14.04 (if it is a sure shot process)

It stuck during installing upgrade at "Preparing fonts-khmeros-core" at terminal last line i see is "preparing to unpack..../fonts - lao_0.0.20060226-9_all.deb....."

Software index is broken - it is impossible to install or remove any software

Comment: Any error messages to show us?

Comment: Kaspar, plz find additional details added

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all the PPA's from your PPA list. Then do a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Thanks Kaspar. How to remove all PPAs? Plz write the command

Comment: Open your dash and type `software`, then open the `Software & Updates` from there. Now open the Other software tab and from the click on PPA's that do not contain your Ubuntu distribution name, and click on the remove button.